# Azure Search, Track deletions don't work

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

As you can see bellow, The "IsActive" column define to detect deletion.
If I go to the DB and change a record "CreationTime" and some data, after running the indexer the changes are applyied in the search service.

Though if I go to the DB and change the IsActive column to 0 (false, since it is a bit column) and the creation time off course, after running the indexer I expect the record to disapear from the search service but it is still there.

[image: defenitions]

Answer (score 5):

When updating `IsActive` column, you need to *also* update `CreationTime` to indicate that the row has changed.

Also, Azure Search sees BIT columns as boolean values instead of 0/1 - so try using "false" as the delete marker value.

Note that SQL integrated change tracking policy would take care of both updates and deletes - consider using it if possible.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I just wanted to add that SQL integrated change tracking only works on tables, not views: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers

Comment: @Ryan, the current docs state that soft delete detection can be used on both tables and views:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#soft-delete-column-deletion-detection-policy
Perhaps that wasn't case back in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

The value needs to be set as a string in quotes, so for you, the exact value that you should put in the field "Delete Market Value is "false" including quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> IsActive column to 0 (false, since it is a bit column)

Here's the problem. According to the newest documentation:

> if you have an integer column where deleted rows are marked with the
>   value 1, use "1". **If you have a BIT column** where deleted rows are
>   marked with the Boolean true value, **use the string literal True or**
>   **true**, the case doesn't matter.

So in my case (BIT column), I've set *true* (without quotes) as delete marker value and everything works like a charm.